# Is there a way to test whether thread safe functions are available in the C standard library?

Tags: c, libc

In regards to the [thread safe functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/help/codes.html#TSF) in newer versions of the C standard library, is there a cross-platform way to tell if these are available via pre-processor definition? I am referring to functions such as `localtime_r()`.

If there is not a standard way, what is the reliable way in GCC? [EDIT] Or posix systems with unistd.h?

Comment: This is what autoconf was born to do.

Comment: Best to use Autoconf.  Autoconf will create the tests for you.

Comment: As above, but use CMake ;)

Comment: Le sigh.  Is it bad if I sincerely wished that autoconf had no purpose? But yeah, I was hoping for pre-processor ideas.

Comment: If it could have been done with the preprocessor, they wouldn't have had to invent autoconf, CMake, etc.

Comment: These functions are mandatory in POSIX, so if `_POSIX_VERSION` is defined to something matching a reasonably-recent version of POSIX after including `unistd.h`, these functions must be available.

Comment: @R.. In POSIX 2004 it was still optional. See http://tinyurl.com/99tl395 and click the [TSF] link next to `localtime_r`. It only became mandatory in POSIX 2008, so you definitely need to check for POSIX 2008 or later. However, the fact that `_POSIX_VERSION` is not defined at all does not mean that the function does not exist. This function is also described as a C extension and thus also supported by many platforms that are not POSIX conform (despite the fact that Linux is not truly POSIX conform in all aspects, even though it may set such a define).

Comment: Ah. Well earlier versions of POSIX have another macro, `_POSIX_THREAD_SAFE_FUNCTIONS`, that's defined if they exist. POSIX 2008 requires this macro to be defined.

Comment: @R.. I will probably accept Mecki's answer, which is nice, but I do think you answered the question very well in your comment for posix systems (with unitstd.h).  You should write it up as a real answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard way to test that, which means there is no way to test it across all platforms. Tools like `autoconf` will create a tiny C program that calls this function and then try to compile and link it. It this works, looks like the function exists, if not, then it may not exist (or the compiler options are wrong and the appropriate `CFLAGS` need to be set).

So you have basically 6 options:

1. Require them to exist. Your code can only work on platforms where they exist; period. If they don't exist, compilation will fail, but that is not your problem, since the platform violates your minimum requirements.
2. Avoid using them. If you use the non-thread safe ones, maybe protected by a global lock (e.g. a mutex), it doesn't matter if they exist or not. Of course your code will then only work on platforms with POSIX mutexes, however, if a platform has no POSIX mutexes, it won't have POSIX threads either and if it has no POSIX threads (and I guess you are probably using POSIX threads w/o supporting any alternative), why would you have to worry about thread-safety in the first place?
3. Decide at runtime. Depending on the platform, either do a "weak link", so you can test at runtime if the function was found or not (a pointer to the function will point to `NULL` if it wasn't) or alternatively resolve the symbol dynamically using something like `dlsym()` (which is also not really portable, but widely supported in the Linux/UNIX world). However, in that case you need a fallback if the function is not found at runtime.
4. Use a tool like `autoconf`, some other tool with similar functionality, or your own configuration script to determine this prior to start of compilation (and maybe set preprocessor macros depending on result). In that case you will also need a fallback solution.
5. Limit usage to well known platforms. Whether this function is available on a certain platform is usually known (and once it is available, it won't go away in the future). Most platforms expose preprocessor macros to test what kind of platform that is and sometimes even which version. E.g. if you know that GNU/Linux, Android, Free/Open/NetBSD, Solaris, iOS and MacOS X all offer this function, test if you are compiling for one of these platforms and if yes, use it. If the code is compiled for another platform (or if you cannot determine what platform that is), it may or may not offer this function, but since you cannot say for sure, better be safe and use the fallback.
6. Let the user decide. Either always use the fallback, unless the user has signaled support or do it the other way round (which makes probably more sense), always assume it is there and in case compilation fails, offer a way the user can force your code into "compatibility mode", by somehow specifying that thread-safe-functions are not available (e.g. by setting an environment variable or by using a different make target). Of course this is the least convenient method for the (poor) user.

Comment: @vonbrand See my reply comment to R..'s comment.

Comment: I actually do like R..'s comment as it sort of does meet my question in a lot of ways.  It's basically a more specific answer to your sub-part (5), which is what I was sort of getting at with my GCC followup question.  Thanks for your writeup, very nice!